# Trouble injecting a Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter instance into my form model

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework2

I'm following this [tutorial](http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/#form-dba) which explains a few approaches to this (I'm doing the first one he lists) and I'm running into some trouble.

My form has Zend\Form\Element\Select populate with values from a DB. Following the tutorial I have this is my controller:

```
...
//So form can pull select list options from DB
$dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
var_dump($dbAdapter); //debug
$form = new UpdateForm($dbAdapter);
...
```

And this in my form model:

```
...
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

class UpdateTicketForm extends Form {
    protected $dbAdapter;

    protected function setDbAdapter(AdapterInterface $dbAdapter) {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
        return $this;
    }

    protected function getDbAdapter() {
        return $this->dbAdapter;
    }

    public function __construct($name = null,AdapterInterface $dbAdapter) {
        $this->setDbAdapter($dbAdapter);
        parent::__construct('updateForm');
...
```

When I run it I can see $dbAdapter dumped to the screen appears to be valid, but I still get an error:

```
object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter)#267 (5) { ["driver":protected]=> object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo)#268 (4) { [...

Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to MyModule\Form\UpdateForm::__construct() must implement interface Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface, none given, called in ...Controller\MyController.php on line 73 and defined in ...\Form\UpdateForm.php on line 20
```

The person who wrote the tutorial also posted his [source](https://github.com/manuakasam/ZF2Playground/tree/master/module/FormDependencies) which I, after looking at, still could not determine the issue with my code (corresponding to the "form-db-adapter" approach in his code)

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: `$name = null,AdapterInterface $dbAdapter` NetBeans screams for this with `wrong order of arguments`

Comment: In addition to the issue mentioned in the two answers, you added the DB adapter code to the `UpdateTicketForm`, but your code is instantiating the `UpdateForm`.

Comment: Yeah that was just a typo, tried to generalize the names in my code before posting to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construtoer of your UpdateForm expects two arguments $name and $adapter as shown below.

```
public function __construct($name = null, AdapterInterface $dbAdapter) {

}
```

So you should pass two arguments while creating the instance of UpdateForm() as shown below.

```
$form = new UpdateForm('formName', $dbAdapter);
```

And if you just want to pass $dbAdapter as the argument change the constructor of UpdateForm to this.

```
public function __construct(AdapterInterface $dbAdapter, $name = null) {

}
```

Comment: When I do that I still get the error: __construct() must implement interface Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface, string given

Answer (score 0):

your form is expecting the DBAdapter as second argument, first argument is form name.
Try the follow:

```
$form = new UpdateForm('myform', $dbAdapter);
```